# Remove separator and change the placement of pages in biblatex' "incollection"

Tags: biblatex

Following the style guidelines from a publisher, I need to tweak two aspects of `biblatex'` way of printing the `incollection` entry in the bibliography.

1. I need to remove the period `.` that appears between the title of the collection and the list of editors, which should start with the word `ed.` with a lowercase `e` (I personally find this very odd, but who am I to disagree).
2. The page sequence should directly precede the publisher's address, and the page sequence should be preceded be a comma.

The entry should in other words look like this:

> Flemming, Edward (2004). "Contrast and perceptual distinctiveness". *Phonetically based phonology* ed. by Bruce Hayes, Robert Kirchner, and Donca Steriade, 232-276. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{flemming2004,
    AUTHOR = "Edward Flemming",
    BOOKTITLE = "Phonetically based phonology",
    EDITOR = "Bruce Hayes and Robert Kirchner and Donca Steriade",
    TITLE = "Contrast and perceptual distinctiveness",
    YEAR = "2004",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PAGES = "232--276",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{flemming2004}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily with a little help of the wonderful [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package and its `\xpatchbibdriver` command.

We use `xpatch` to suppress the punctuation before the `editor`s. Then we move the `page` to right after the `series+number` macro (which gives the appropriate position for your example, I'm not sure about others, so if you are not satisfied with the position, leave a comment below.): first we remove the macro from it's old position and then we insert it at the new one.

```
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\nopunct\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{\typeout{failed to patch bibmacro incollection to remove punctuation before byeditors}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}
  {}{\typeout{failed to patch bibmacro incollection to remove page macro}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}{\typeout{failed to patch bibmacro incollection to re-add page macro}}
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{flemming2004,
    AUTHOR = "Edward Flemming",
    BOOKTITLE = "Phonetically based phonology",
    EDITOR = "Bruce Hayes and Robert Kirchner and Donca Steriade",
    TITLE = "Contrast and perceptual distinctiveness",
    YEAR = "2004",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PAGES = "232--276",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\nopunct\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{\typeout{failed to patch bibmacro incollection to remove punctuation before byeditors}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}
  {}{\typeout{failed to patch bibmacro incollection to remove page macro}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
  {\usebibmacro{series+number}
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}{\typeout{failed to patch bibmacro incollection to re-add page macro}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{flemming2004}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Great! This answer works great on other "change placement" -type problems, too.